# Get size of sub/superscript

Tags: fontsize, subscripts

I would like to get the value of the font size of the selected text.

For example, for an article with a global font size is 12pt, I want to know the font size of the corresponding sub/superscript (maybe 7pt or something). If we change the font size of a particular paragraph to 10pt, so what is the font size of the sub/superscript size in this case (should be less than 7pt).

Below is an example, instead of font size, I just know the syntax for the width size of a string. By trying that, I got the width of a selected text but cannot know the width of the subscript.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newsavebox\thefontsize
\newcommand{\sizecheck}[1]{\sbox{\thefontsize}{#1}\the\wd\thefontsize}

\begin{document}

\(\sizecheck{a}\)

\(b_{\sizecheck{a}}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused: the sizes are saved in the macros `\tf@size`, `\sf@size`, and `\ssf@size`, but then you talk about the *width* of a subscript, which depends on the subscript itself... What output do you exactly expect?

Comment: @campa, Thank you for answering. For a 12pt-size document, I want to use a command like `\sizecheck{text}`, and the output is `12`. Now, if I use `$b_{\sizecheck{test}}$`, the output should be the font size of this subscript. How do I obtain that?

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?  If it's the width you want, you could pack it in a box with `\scriptstyle` (or appropriate equivalent) and then check on the width of the box.

Comment: @barbara beeton: my old code is to define an overbar of a math character. I want to utilize this code and want to change some measure units into an adaptive version which depends on font size. If I use `f@size`, the subscript has a size equaling to text size. That is why I want to find the font size of the subscript.

Comment: This is a typical XY problem. Why didn't you ask about *that*?

Comment: @campa: Yes, I can ask directly my final aim, but this topic is also interesting to me. So I will say this is a minor question to know the font size of a subscript to check sometimes. Therefore, I ask this first to apply for my old code, if I fail, I will ask for a new topic. Thanks to your previous answer but currently, I am not successful to apply for it.